# Android Base64 decoding for Android 2.1

Tags: java, android, base64

I'm building an application with API Level 7 (Android 2.1) and I need to decode a string received by server,which is encoded with Base64. I know that Base64 library is included in Android 2.2, that's why I include the source code of it directly in my project. You can find the source code here: [Base64](http://www.frankdu.com/notes/2011/01/27/base64-encoding-with-android-2-1-or-earlier/).

So my problem is that when I try to decode a string the base64 returns this: `BASE 64 : [B@46392d10`.

If I run the code that server send me on online base64 decoder I get this: `le":"en_US","id":2,"error_code":6003,"error_string":"Unsupported Client Version"}`

Here is the code that I'm using :

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
Log.v("Response ","Status line : "+ response.getStatusLine().toString());
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); //response
Log.v("Response ","Response : "+ responseBody);

String objectIdentificator = responseBody.substring(0,32);
Log.v("Response ","Object Identificator (LONGINT) : "+ objectIdentificator);

String type = responseBody.substring(33,36);
Log.v("Response ","TYPE (UNSIGNED BYTE) : "+ type);

String operation = responseBody.substring(37,40);
Log.v("Response ","OPERATION (UNSIGNED BYTE) : "+ operation);

String objectId = responseBody.substring(41, 73);
Log.v("Response ","UID (CHAR, length 32) : "+ objectId);

String id = responseBody.substring(74, 106);
Log.v("Response ","ID (LONGINT) : "+ id);

String size = responseBody.substring(107,139);
Log.v("Response ","Data Size (LONGINT) : "+ size);

String hash = responseBody.substring(140,172);
Log.v("Response ","Data Hash (CHAR, length 32 : "+ hash);

String dType = responseBody.substring(173,176);
Log.v("Response ","Data Type (UNSIGNED BYTE) : "+ dType);

String data = responseBody.substring(177, responseBody.length());
Log.v("Response ","Data (CHAR, any length, in BASE64) : "+ data);
String first = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT).toString();
Log.v("Response ","BASE 64 : "+ first);
```

Any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: The above link is broken. It appears to be moved [to here](http://www.frankdu.com/?p=225).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I hope it helps to someone else : )

Comment: Be careful, I've used the code of Base64 to encode an image in a mobile app and got some problems when decoding the image in a server, I had to move to Android 2.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with `Base64`.

The `Base64` class correctly returns a `byte[]` that contains the data. You call `toString()` on that `byte[]` which does **not** use the *content* of the `byte[]` but *only* its `identityHashCode()`.

What you *want* to do instead is convert your `byte[]` into a `String` by giving the correct encoding:

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
String string = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read how to use it? It's at the top of the page you linked, you couldn't have missed it :) `decode()` returns a byte array, you need to convert that to `String`. *Not* by calling `toString()`.